# After uninstalling modules using Composer and removing all trace of them, Magento is still looking for them via ModuleList\Loader->getModuleConfigs()

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3.1

I'm trying to remove some modules (all Amasty modules) from my site for debugging purposes, but no matter what I do, Magento keeps looking for the Amasty_Base module and I can't get rid of it.

The modules were initially installed via Composer. So first I removed the modules from `composer.json` and ran `composer update` which duly removed them. Then I ran `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and cleared all caches as usual.

I also removed all mention of the modules from the `core_config_data` and `setup_module` database tables, and for good measure I deleted all the usual Magento cache and generated code directories and cleared Redis cache.

However, when loading my site I get the following exception which shows that Magento is still looking for a `amasty/base/etc/module.xml` file:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The contents from the "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/amasty/base/etc/module.xml" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/amasty/base/etc/module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File\Interceptor->fileGetContents('/var/www/vhosts/...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList/Loader.php:120]
#2 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList\Loader->getModuleConfigs() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList/Loader.php:81]
#3 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList\Loader->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList.php:72]
#4 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList->getAll() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList.php:92]
#5 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList->getOne('CoolPartner_Integrat...') called at [vendor/CoolPartner/magento2-integration/src/Integration/Helper/Data.php:36]
#6 CoolPartner\Integration\Helper\Data->getExtensionVersion() called at [vendor/CoolPartner/magento2-integration/src/Integration/Model/SDKInitializer.php:96]
#7 CoolPartner\Integration\Model\SDKInitializer->execute() called at [vendor/CoolPartner/magento2-integration/src/Integration/Plugin/AppFrontControllerPlugin.php:42]
#8 CoolPartner\Integration\Plugin\AppFrontControllerPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000005404ea3200000000756a40ab#, &Closure#000000005404ea2d00000000756a40ab#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000005404e62700000000756a40ab#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000005404e62700000000756a40ab#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000005404e62700000000756a40ab#), array(array('storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'), 'requestPreproces...')) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000005404e62700000000756a40ab#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000005404edf400000000756a40ab#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

I grepped through the code base looking for anything remotely mentioning Amasty or Amasty_Base but I can't find anything.

I've made sure all caches are off and cleared, and all pre-compiled code is gone etc.

Curiously, I even edited `Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar` and added an `exit` statement in the `register` function, but nothing seemed to reach that point in the code.

What have I missed? Am I misunderstanding Magento somehow?

Comment: Did you run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command? if not, please execute it as well

Comment: @ShoaibMunir Yes, and I am in Developer Mode as well which means code compilation is not necessary. I also deleted the `generated` folder which clears compiled code several times.

Comment: then try this `composer remove Amasty/Base` and run magento commands after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be caused (at least in part) by Zend OpCache; a type of PHP code cache which had been set up on the server. It was solved by restarting the `httpd` and `php-fpm` services, and then configuring Zend OpCache to revalidate PHP files based on timestamps (which can be disabled when running sites in production mode, as long as care is taken to flush the opcache or restart web server as above).

In `/etc/php-fpm.d/example.com.conf` add something like:

```
php_value[opcache.validate_timestamps] = 1
php_value[opcache.revalidate_freq] = 0
```

Then restart httpd and php-fpm.

Comment: Thank you I forgot to look there (again).

Answer (score 0):

It is happening for me on php7.4 and server is apache2.
My module is completely removed but I'm getting same error as above.
Please advise how can I fix it.
Thanks a million!!